# What is a word for "detaining without trial"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I read this in a news about the passing away of a prominent political figure. One of the critics mentioned that during the time when he was in power he used to "detain without trial" his political oppositions to silence them.

In the news they used a single word for that phrase, but I can't remember it.

**What is a word for "detaining without trial"?**

I've tried to search for "detain without trial", "imprisonment without proper trial", "detaining without hearing", etc (without the quotes), but all I could find were *internment*, which is more about concentration camp, or *remand*, which is about the pre-trial detention. (I hope by putting what I searched for, future people who search for the same thing will find this page with the answer!)

The word I'm looking for seems to mean that the people never went through any trial at all, and so the prominent political figure _____ the political oppositions.

Comment: It's usually called _Disappearing_. It's a causative transitive usage of _disappear_, meaning 'cause to disappear'. The term got popular as a borrowing/translation of the Spanish phrase _los desaparecidos_ 'the disappeared (ones)', referring to the thousands of civilians kidnapped and killed in secret by Latin American dictatorships in the last half of the 20th century.

Comment: Given that the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_detention_without_trial) on the subject refers to strictly as "detention without trial", I am going to say there is no shorter phrase in common use.

Comment: Disappearing doesn't seem like it. I feel that it's a political term. I remembered googling for the definition and it has a definition, so it should be a word. I can't find them in the history on my local computer, though, I must have done it in other browser.

Comment: *Gitmo* (*GTMO*) or *Guantanamo* might get the point across. Coin a verb: *The prominent political figure gitmoed the opposition leader.* (And +1 for *disappearing*.)

Comment: In French (in France) they have *garde à vue*.

Comment: I think “detained without trial” is borderline redundant and that just “detained” would imply that no trial has occurred (detained pending trial) or even that no charges have been made (detained pending indictment). “Detained indefinitely” or “detained for years” would make it clearer, but “without trial” is not required and just “detained” by itself (without “indefinitely” or “for years”) is sufficient in this context, imo.

Comment: "Attainder" has been used in this sense, historically.  Also, "suspension of habeas corpus" indirectly enables this.

Comment: And how could one forget "internment", used for Americans of Japanese descent during WWII and, I believe, in Northern Ireland during the "Troubles" there.  (Oh, I see you already mentioned internment.  But you shouldn't discount it out of hand.)

Comment: @HotLicks The question itself did mention "internment".

Comment: ("Internment" does not mean "concentration camps".)

Comment: @HotLicks: Yeah, I was just putting a word for *internment* which I think is most related to it. I just knew this word when I did the search, though, so my definition might not be really correct indeed. Perhaps my memory was wrong, and looking from the answers, *internment* seems like the best choice for the phrase "detain without trial". Does everyone agree that *internment* matches "detain without trial" as a single word request?

Comment: @justhalf You may or may not have been thinking of /habeas corpus/. On second thought, there is already an answer to this effect

Comment: Try this on for size : denial of habeas corpus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word I would use is *internment* (as identified in the question), which [Wikipedia describes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internment) as

> the imprisonment or confinement of people, commonly in large groups, without trial

though I would not see it as necessarily going as far as the extremely negative associations of *concentration camps* from World War II.

For individuals rather than groups, I might use *detention*, which I would almost never use for being held before a trial (instead using *remand*) or after a trial (instead using *prison*).

Comment: +1 and accepted. Not really what in my mind as I remember it (and I can't find the verb form), but I think this matches my description quite well. Perhaps some mismatch is due to my incorrect memory.

Comment: The verb is *intern* (and so *interning* and *interned*) and is transitive - though there is the risk that somebody might now read it as unpaid training.

Answer (score 4):

*[Immure](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/immure)* is a possibility:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   Enclose or confine (someone) against their will:

*The prominent political figure **immured** his political opponents.*

Comment: How does this mean without trial? Most imprisonment is against the will of the imprisoned.

Comment: Interestingly, after consulting freedictionary, Oxford Advanced Learner's dictionary, OED, Dictionary.com, Collins, McMillan, Longman DCE and Merriam Webster, none of the above named resources has mentioned anything relating to "against one's will".

The only source that has mentioned this is http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/immure
And this website suggests us to refer to Oxford advanced learner (which did not record this denotation)
Please takes note of this when using this verb to denote "against one's will"

Comment: OED is rarely wrong, but I used the less exhaustive ODO. The [corpus](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22immure%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1945,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) can speak for itself.

Answer (score 2):

*[Impound](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/impound)* includes imprisonment, and is not normally associated with the due process normally offered to people:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
> 1.0 Seize and take legal custody of (something, especially a vehicle, goods, or documents) because of an infringement of a law:
>
> 2.0 Shut up (domestic animals) in a pound or enclosure:
>
> 2.1 Lock up (someone):

In situations where political prisoners are taken and help without due process, it is normally rationalized in a tyrannical legal framework:

*The prominent political figure **impounded** his political opposition.*

Comment: It seems that this carries the meaning of "infringement of a law", while in my description, it is in the borderline of whether it's a violation of the law, because the political figure might just looking for arbitrary reasons to confine the oppositions. +1 for the connotation that you mentioned, though.

Comment: Agreed, @justhalf. I like your question. We will probably have a hard time finding anything better than *internment*, which generally suspends the legal consideration of *habeas corpus*  under the extenuating conditions of war. Under the conditions you describe, tyrants still maintain a pretext of legal consideration--even if it is transparently contrived.

Answer (score 0):

**Imprisonment/imprison** (v.)

According to Jowitt’s Dictionary of English Law,

imprisonment means:

> The restraint of a person's liberty under the custody of another. It extends in law to confinement not only in a gaol but in a house, or stocks, or to holding a man in the street, etc.; for in all these cases the person so restrained is said to be a prisoner, so long as he has not his liberty freely to go about his business as at other times (Co.Litt. 253). Imprisonment may be lawful or unlawful.

"Detain without trial" must be unlawful, and, therefore, imprisonment would be appropriate in this context. More importantly, in theory, Courts are the only authority who have the lawful authority to imprison a person. As in your context, the person who imprisoned the opposition is a politician, it is therefore clear that the use of "imprisonment" here must convey a sense of "unlawfulness".

However, I would suggest that, for the sake of accuracy, you should use **Unlawful/political** imprisonment. **False** imprisonment is another term which has similar meaning, but you should be cautious when using this word, as legally it confers some special meaning.

Comment: "Detain without trial" is only unlawful when the laws are not sufficiently bent.  "Internment" and "suspension of habeas corpus" has been done several times in both US and UK history.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was intended to refer merely to the situation described in the question.
However, I am not sure what precisely do you mean by saying "the laws are not sufficiently bent."

Comment: But the OP does not indicate that whatever was done was technically illegal (in whatever country where it was done).

Comment: "he used to "detain without trial" his political oppositions to *silence* them."
"imprisonment without *proper* trial"
"people *never went through any trial at all*"
The above quotations from the OP connote - Improper motive, procedural unfairness, indefinite detention without trial

The necessary inference is that they all point to the direction of unlawfulness, and, as you said somewhere else, it is very likely that they amount to habeas corpus.

Comment: English kings used to do the exact same thing, and, at the time, it was all perfectly legal (so long as the Church didn't object), since the king answered only to God.

Comment: That is a valid obversation. As a matter of legal principles, there are always exceptions. Exceptions, however, remain exceptional. Unless the OP refers to the King in historical time, i believe that such a narrow exception should be ignored.

Comment: The OP appears to be referring to some country other than the US or the UK, and there are many countries in the world that lack the basic legal protections we take for granted.

Comment: I completely agree with the latter part of your sentence. Unfortunately, I, with respect, do not think that your statement is an appropriate counterargument to my suggestion. Anyway, this is a potentially interesting topic but here might not be an appropriate place to discuss (Unfortunately I have been advised to avoid extended discussion by the system!:P. But that is indeed a very thought-provoking topic!

Answer (score 0):

*[Incarcerate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incarcerate)*:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   Imprison or confine:

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a legal phrase to refer to, then you might refer to the **writ of Habeas corpus** or in your case someone violating the **writ of Habeas corpus** -- here is a small excerpt from what it states:

> "...demands that a prisoner be taken before the court, and that the
>   custodian present proof of authority, allowing the court to determine
>   whether the custodian has lawful authority to detain the prisoner"

Abraham Lincoln suspended the writ of Habeas corpus during the Civil War.

Answer (score -1):

[Confinement](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/confinement):

> - The act of confining or the state of being confined.

[to confine](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/confine):

> - To shut or keep in, especially to imprison. (AHD)

The Free Disctionary

Comment: Without a trial?

Comment: I think this lacks the "without trial" part, but otherwise it's going to the same direction.

Comment: I don't think a confinement is strictly linked to a trial. A prison is just one of the places were can be confined.

Answer (score -1):

[kidnap](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/kidnap) - Abduct (someone) and hold them captive, albeit typically to obtain a ransom.

See also:

[abduct](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abduct#abduct__3) - Take (someone) away illegally by force or deception

Comment: Kidnap and abduct doesn't seem like it, they are detained in the prison, so I don't think that qualifies as kidnap or abduct. Also it lacks the political nuance. =)

Comment: Ok - on trying to find another useful synonym I found [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_kidnapping). Does it cover what you want?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps "custody sans trial" will work.

Answer (score -1):

INTERNMENT:
This is a political word for detaining a person without trial. "Internment" was  commonly used for IRA members who were detained without trial.

Comment: This is a good word but was already suggested 2 years ago [above](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/239808/184766)